# Make entire column disappear

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I make the left column in a table disappear using plain JS?

This is my approach:

```
<table id="tab" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>def</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ghi</td>
        <td>jkl</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>mno</td>
        <td>pqr</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="inv()">invisible</button>
<button onclick="vis()">visible</button>

<script>
var tab, td;
window.onload = function() {
    tab = document.getElementById("tab");
    td = tab.getElementsByTagName("td");
}

function inv() {
    for (i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
        td[i].style.display = "none";
        i++;
    }
}

function vis() {
    for (i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
        td[i].style.display = "block";
        i++;
    }
}
</script>
```

It works, but I have to use "ugly" loops.
Maybe there is a more efficient way by just saying `column[0].display = "none"`.

[Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/4L4h7ea1/)

Comment: Try using jQuery, it would be as easy as `$('#tab tr td:first-child').hide()`

Comment: Have you actually tested your own code? The code you should hides all cells not just the ones in a specific column. And setting `display` to `block` for table cells with break the layout. They need to be set to `table-cell` instead.

Comment: @RoToRa: Of course I have. Why should it hide all cells?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take advantage of CSS hierarchy and `nth-child` selectors.

Use selector `tr td:nth-child(1)` to select all the first column td elements.

[**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/4L4h7ea1/1/)

```js
var tab;
// Use DOMContentLoaded instead of load event
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  tab = document.getElementById('tab');
});

function inv() {
  tab.classList.add('hide');
}

function vis() {
  tab.classList.remove('hide');
}
```

```css
.hide tr td:nth-child(1) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="tab" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>def</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ghi</td>
    <td>jkl</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mno</td>
    <td>pqr</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="inv()">invisible</button>
<button onclick="vis()">visible</button>
```

Demo using toggle with single button.

```js
function toggle() {
  document.getElementById('tab').classList.toggle('hide');
}
```

```css
.hide tr td:nth-child(1) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="tab" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>def</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ghi</td>
    <td>jkl</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mno</td>
    <td>pqr</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="toggle()">Toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

By the use of some empty css classes and jQuery, you are able to achieve that in a one-liner:

```
<table id="tab" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">abc</td>
        <td class="col2">def</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">ghi</td>
        <td class="col2">jkl</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td class="col1">mno</td>
        <td class="col2">pqr</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

now you can just do:

```
 jQuery(".col1").hide();
```

(mind the selector with a dot before the class name)

Comment: Don't see jQuery tag or mention in the question. OP mentioned _"using plain JS?"_

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient solution would be to inject and remove a stylesheet and let the browser do the work.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4L4h7ea1/2/

```
var tab, td;

var hideFirstColumnCss = document.createElement('style');
hideFirstColumnCss.setAttribute('id', 'hideCssStyle');
hideFirstColumnCss.innerHTML = '#tab td:first-child { display: none; }';
window.onload = function () {
    tab = document.getElementById("tab");
    td = tab.getElementsByTagName("td");

}

function inv() {
    document.head.appendChild(hideFirstColumnCss);
}

function vis() {
    var style = document.getElementById('hideCssStyle');
    style.parentNode.removeChild(style);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the row tags to get to your cells to hide/show them. That way you can specify an index for the row as all cells are direct children of their row.

```
var tab, td;
window.onload = function () {
    tab = document.getElementById("tab");
    tr = tab.getElementsByTagName("tr");

}

function inv() {
    for (i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
        tr[i].children[0].style.display = "none";
    }
}

function vis() {
    for (i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
        tr[i].children[0].style.display = "block";
    }
}
```